# Custom Background Color Wordpress Plugin WP Table Reloadad

Tags: html, wordpress, background-color, html-table

I am using Wp Table Reloaded Plugin in Wordpress on This Site :

```
http://equinoximpex.inditalent.com/acid-dyes/
```

On this page in second column name of shade, i want use different color in every next box like,

```
http://www.equinoximpex.com/acid-dyes.html
```

Tried to using

```
<div style="background-color:#xyz;"></div>
```

But not Work, want to use custom color in each box.

I dont have knowledge of php,,, but good knowledge of Css and Html.

So please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the Div a height and width. Say:

```
<div style="background-color: yellow; height: 25px; width: 35px;"></div>
```